# Develop a Family Tree Portal with several functinality

Tags: asp.net, .net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5, family-tree

We need to develop a family tree portal which also supports functinality like

1. Portal Framework (Sub portal)
2. Dashboard
3. Blogs, Forums, Events, Polls, Task
4. Member subscription
5. Advertisement
6. Chat
7. Broadcast
8. Document Management
9. Personalization
10. Alerts & Reminders

And above all **Family tree**

It is also decided to build family tree from scratch and develop UI in Flex.

I am planning to develop it in DNN as i feel other modules are freely available in DNN

Questions

1) Is all listed modules freely available in DNN ...if yes can you provide link?
2) Do i need to consider any other Opensource CMS like umbraco or any other suggestion
3) Very unlikely...But should i develop it from scratch

Limitation : I will not be able to afford costly CMS

Development Platform : ASP .Net 3.5 & SQL Server 2008

Please suggest

Comment: Not an answer but an important sidenote : I have build something similar to this once (it was PHP) but eventually had to stop due to problems with privacy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start here for a list of modules in DNN - http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Development/Downloads/ProjectsDownloads/tabid/1373/Default.aspx also snowcovered has a lot of modules for sale most are resonable - http://snowcovered.com